# Magento Extension for FREQUENTLY PURCHASED TOGETHER option

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to implement "FREQUENTLY PURCHASED TOGETHER" in my product view page. Also, to implement Color and Size Swatch. Please guide me best to or best extension to implement same. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Dear Enigmativity i have posted question at "magento.stackexchange.com" but there i did not received any response. Infact missed your comment also there.... so i came here.. and got proper tag for magento too... and got solution too.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below mentioned extensions are widely used for frequently bought together option.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/frequently-bought-together-extension.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/frequently-bought-together-2.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/frequently-bought-together-3.html